# Undefined is not an object React Native StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I have been trying to get a simple React Native StackNavigation example app working, however I keep getting an

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')`

I am not expecting the app to navigate anywhere at this stage, simply deploy with an app bar and some arbitrary text.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Text} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <Text> Hello World </Text>
    );
  }
}

const appScreens = StackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: App},
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('IntervalTimer', () => appScreens);
```

The error is reporting on the `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` declaration. And removing this line does allow the app to deploy but with no header as I would expect.

`StackNavigator` was installed using NPM and is being imported into the app fine.

There are similar questions posted and I have tried their suggestions. Appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

You can add initialRouteName on StackNavigator's option. Try this.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {AppRegistry, Text} from 'react-native';
    import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

    class App extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home',
      };

      render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <Text> Hello World </Text>
        );
      }
    }

    export const appScreens = StackNavigator({
      Home: { screen: App }
    },{
      initialRouteName: Home
    })

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('IntervalTimer', () => appScreens);
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just that the prop might have a chance of being undefined, you can just check for undefined.

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation || {};
```

Assuming at some point the `navigation` is defined in render, the above should be safe to use. You can try logging it and see if it is always undefined or it gets defined at some point.

```
console.log(navigate)
```

The output might be...

```
undefined
undefined
//defined
```